# Adding Minecraft default buildings

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

Is there any way to insert default buildings in Minecraft Bedrock in Playstation 4 in creative mode?

Example: I would like to add villager houses and buildings to make a village faster, without the need to create each house and building block by block.

Answer (score 2):

## Structure Blocks

There is a block called a [Structure Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block) which can be used to place structures. In Java Edition, this includes vanilla structures. Unfortunately, in Bedrock Edition, [they cannot place vanilla structures by default](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block#Load:%7E:text=Vanilla%20NBT%20structure%20files%20cannot%20be%20loaded%20with%20structure%20block.). However, you could use the save mode to save the house you want to copy, and the load mode to load in the copied structure. See the wiki page for more details.

## `/structure` Command

In BE, there is also the [`/structure`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/structure) command, but it also appear that it is unable to place vanilla structures.

Comment: I already use it. It is a good solution, but it is a copy-paste solution for already built structures. I will mark your answer if we have no more of them